# how do you make a text box and a longest word button in javascript to find the longest word in a phrase on html

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

file with a text box and a Longest Word button. In case of ties as in "Many dogs are nice", you can identify any of the longest words as the longest.

Comment: Please add what you have tried in terms of code and also please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question a bit differently and possibly asking a few questions instead. Here are a series of questions that are a bit more direct and will lead you to the right answer (you can google for these too): 1) how do I identify the longest string within another string (answer, first tokenize then loop and identify), 2)   How do I do this in JS, 3) How do I  place a text box and button a page, 4) how do I make a button click run some javascript, 5) how can I read the contents of text box in JS. 6) how do I write text on the screen from JS.

Answer (score 1):

A function that gets a string and returns the longest word in it:

```
function getLongestWord(txt) {
    var longestWord = "";
    var words = txt.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        if(words[i].length > longestWord.length)
            longestWord = words[i];
    return longestWord;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `longestWord` - which at the beginning is empty - will hold our
  current longest word.
- Since space separates different words, the function first splits the
  input string based on space character and stores them into an array.
- We iterate through array of words and check length of each one of them. If
  the new word has a bigger length, it'll replace the `longestWord`,
  otherwise no change and we go to next word till all words are checked.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
<button id="longestBtn">Find the longest word</button>
<input id="longestWrd" type="text" disabled />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('longestBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var txt = document.getElementById('myText').value;
    var lw = getLongestWord(txt);
    var wrd = document.getElementById('longestWrd');
    wrd.value = lw + " (" + lw.length + ")";
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/utgtwxt0/)

Test input:

> file with a text box and a Longest Word button. In case of ties as in
>   "Many dogs are nice", you can identify any of the longest words as the
>   longest.

Output:

> identify (8)

Comment: This answer works, but I think you should describe the theory not just give the answer.